# Как остановить setinterval?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Имеется функция. Вызывается автоматический таймер, который меняет картинки через определенный промежуток времени.

```
function timer(flag){
    var intervalId = setInterval (function(){...}
    if (flag == 'false') {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
             }
}
```

Вызываю эту функцию с параметром `false`

```
timer('false');
```

Работает и останавливает.

Хочу при нажатии на картинку вызвать эту функцию и остановить таймер и затем заново запустить от того момента, с которого я нажал на картинку. 
Пишу

```
$("#cimg2").click(function(event){
    timer('false');//останавливает таймер
    ...
    код//выполняет нужный мне код
    timer();//опять запускается таймер
}
```

Не работает и не останавливает. Убирал `timer(); в $("#cimg2").click(function(event)`, чтобы проверить, остановит ли он таймер, - не остановил. Не могу понять, почему в данном случае он не останавливает таймер, и как сделать, чтобы заработал.

Comment: @harley, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.
______

Напишите var intervalId; перед function timer(){} а внутри функции var не пишите. Только непонятно, зачем вам это, если у вас код по клику синхронный, то interval не сработает, пока выполняется ваш код.

Answer (score 2):

setTimeout, setInterval можно отменить функциями clearTimeout и clearInterval:

```
var idIntervals=0;
function timer(){
    //to do something.
}

$("#cimg2").click(function(event){
  clearInterval(idIntervals);//тут останавливаем таймер
  idIntervals=setInterval(function(){timer();},1000);//опять запускается таймер
}
```